# Getting height of the view is zero

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this button:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        style="@style/UiStylePositive"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/default_shadow"
        android:elevation="@dimen/margin_32dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/button_cancel_shadow"
        android:text="@string/button_not_use"
        android:textColor="@color/red" />
```

Here is the command that I use to get the size of the button in the fragment:

```
var btnHeight = binding.btnCancel.height
```

I try to use this command in lifecycle functions like onViewCreated and onCreateView but the result is zero.

My question is what lifecycle functions can I use to get the height of the view?

Comment: What does `UiStylePositive` look like?

Comment: You can't use it until its actually been laid out.  That's not a part of the lifecycle of any component, as the lifecycle of Activities and Fragments don't cover drawing. 
 What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the post.
I need it to calculate the size of the text based on size of the view.

Comment: Why not use the built in autosizing?  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the link. I do not sure that it will work for with buttons.

Comment: @Michael A button is a text view with a background.  Literally-  Button derives from TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver) to set up a listener for when the view is getting laid out - you probably want an [`OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)

```
someContainingView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    // update your things when size > 0
}
```

You can set that on any view, so you could add it to the `Button` itself, or the top of the view hierarchy. I haven't really used it much so I don't know what you need to watch out for, but it's the approach a lot of official code samples use when you need to get the size of a thing after it's been laid out